# which statistical sampling technique to employ to have a representative sample

Tags: sampling, stratification, cluster-sample

There is kwashiorkor outbreak in my community Abeng (a city in Africa). The community is in sections A to F and it heterogeneous in nature.

Comment: It is very unlikely that people here recognise all the specific details here: korshiorkor? Abeng? sections A to F? I fail all these tests. Unless you can make this much more specific, it is likely that this question will be closed as unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a representative sample of the entire community then you could randomly sample from the whole community, picking names randomly from a census list, if there is one.

However, this is unlikely to be the best method. You will likely want some from of stratified sample (to match the relative proportions of the sections) and then clustered (to make the process easier to implement).

Then you will need to adjust all estimates to suit the sampling method.

This sort of issue has been studied quite a lot; you may want to consult an expert.